# Datepicker content control - extract value into another document using VBA in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have two Word documents (Doc1.docm) and (Doc2.docm). In Doc1.docm, I select a month and a year (the format: MMMM YYYY), using the Date Picker content control. I defined this Date Picker field as "Date1".

I am trying to automnatically update a new content field in Doc2.docm in the header when I select a month and year in Doc1.docm.

I can do this in the same document using just Doc1.docm when using this code:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim CCtrl As ContentControl
If ContentControl.Title = "Date1" Then
  For Each CCtrl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If CCtrl.Title = "Date2" Then
      With CCtrl
        .LockContents = False
        .Range.Text = Format(ContentControl.Range.Text, "MMMM YYYY")  
        .LockContents = True  
      End With  
      Exit For  
    End If  
    Next  
End If  
End Sub
```

Does anyone know how I can update Doc2.docm when I select a month and year in Doc1.docx?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to open the other Word document. This can be achieved programatically via:

```
Dim wordDoc as object
Set wordDoc = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wordDoc.Documents.Open("C:\Doc2.docm")
```

You can now manipulate the contents of Doc2.docm programatically, just like you are doing it with Doc1.docm. If you are wondering why the document doesn't show up: it's hidden. To make it visible you have to set `wordDoc.Visible = True`. Don't forget to close Doc2 once the changes have been made via `WordDoc.Quit`

Comment: Now what do I do to fix my code in order to use that? I have `CCtrl` defining both Date1 and Date2 with the `For each` statement. I'm confused as to how I could fix the code with what you have here.